# Tornehave's preprint "On BSG and the symmetric groups"

Tags: reference-request, at.algebraic-topology

There are a few papers that cite Tornehave's preprint entitled *On BSG and the symmetric groups* apparently dating from early 70s or late 60s. Google search reveals very little. Does anyone have access to this preprint?

Comment: "A few" is probably quite an understatement.  This paper is cited all over the place!

Comment: Just came across this looking for the same preprint. Did anyone ever find it?

Comment: Hello, I am still looking for this. Anyone have any luck?

Comment: I emailed Tornehave's university and they could not find it in their library unfortunately.